# Android: выровнять TextView по линии верхней части ImageView

Tags: android, xml

Как в `RealtiveLayout` выровнять `TextView` по линии верхней части `ImageView`? Верхняя часть буквы "З" должна касаться фиолетовой линии)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал `android:includeFontPadding="false"` - эффекта нет.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    card:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardInnerContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inbox_cardPadding">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardIcon"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            card:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CardTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="Заголовок"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Скриншот с экрана телефона (эмулятор не использую):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте TextView в лайаут, для пущей ясности вопроса,а то не понятно где он и как вы его задаете. Могу предположить что можно в дополнение к `android:includeFontPadding=false` в TextView добавить еще `android:padding=0dp`, но не уверен что сработает.

Comment: возможно поможет `alignBaseline`

Comment: Не помогло. Вообщем я на данный момент задал отрицательный margin заголовку.

Comment: впринципе можно рассчитать, расстояние. 
А вы будете менять стиль текста? если нет то это просто, если да, то нужно писать будет под новый стиль.